# How to extend a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile` that is similar to all of my builds. It only differs in the `EXPOSE <Port>`.

Question: how could I create some kind of a template-dockerfile that I could simply reuse across all of my projects?

I must put the template dockerfile in another (gitlab) repository, some kind of "docker-commons".

For example (the exact details of the dockerfile are not important for my question);

`Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-11 as build
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src
RUN mvn package
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/*.jar extract

FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=build /extract/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build /extract/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=build /extract/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build /extract/application/ ./

EXPOSE 8090
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

From a programmers point of view, I want to create a "static base template" that I can pass the "port" parameter. Something like:

`Dockerfile`:

```
extends base_dockerfile
EXPOSE 8090
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Finally, I would then want to use that Dockerfile in different `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: `FROM base_dockerfile`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerfile FROM Instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39442164/dockerfile-from-instruction)

Comment: No, I'm simply looking for a way to "inherit" all definitions written in a base dockerfile.

Comment: So why isn't FROM suitable? The layers of `base_dockerfile` will simply be incorporated into your new image, followed by any layers your new image adds.

Comment: Because my base dockerfile should not actually **build** layers (because there is no source code next to the base dockerfile that could be included). It should only inherit the build definitions to the child, so that the child builds the layers.

Comment: docker does not have the concept is something like composable Dockerfiles.  Either use the suggested FROM instruction aka the builder pattern, or roll your own templating pipeline, which can actually be found in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

If the only params that change is the port you want to expose, you can override it whe you run the container. You don't need to expose a port in the Dockerfile, just bind it when you run the container.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Using `-p` flag
`docker run -p 80:80/tcp -p 80:80/udp ...`

Or using ports in docker-compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network)

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8090"
  db:
    image: postgres

networks:
  default:
    # Use a custom driver
    driver: custom-driver-1
```

---

**Edit**:
if you already have an image on a registry you can simply reference it

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    image:gitlab.simultech.it:4567/<project_path>
    ports:
      - "8000:8090"
  db:
    image: postgres

networks:
  default:
    # Use a custom driver
    driver: custom-driver-1
```

`docker run -p 80:80/tcp -p 80:80/udp gitlab.simultech.it:4567/<project_path>`

Comment: That looks promising. How could I reference my dockerfile if it is placed into different (`gitlab`) repository? Because, I could only use it across different projects if I put it somewhere into a "commons" repository.

Comment: To run your dockerfile you need build an image. You can build your dockerfile inside a gitlab-ci pipeline, publish the image on a registry (gitlab offer a registry) and the use the address to the image (eg gitlab.simultech.it:4567/<project_path>). Here and example of gitlab pipeline https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html.

Comment: Yes I know, but the question is still: how can I reference the `docker-commons/base-dockerfile` inside a project-specific `docker-compose.yml` or project specific `gitlab_ci.yml`? Cause I then cannot simply write `build: .` in my project, as the common base `Dockerfile` does not exist there.

Comment: You would need to pull that file from where it resides.

Comment: And that would be done how? With a `curl` before I run `script: docker build .`?

Comment: Yeah, I'd think something like that could work. Or perhaps a git submodule.